# Python class setter - are class attributes reassigned every time a new instance is created?

Tags: python, class, attributes, getter-setter, metaclass

I'm trying to create a class with a base attribute shared by all instances that is used as a template when initialising an instance attribute. Ideally, it would be final/immutable but this is Python so I'm just not going to overwrite it.

```
class Foo:
    class_template_attr = some_resource_intensive_operation()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance_attr = method_using_class_attribute()
            
    def method_using_class_attribute():
        # determine instance_specific_extras
        return self.class_template_attr + instance_specific_extras
```

I'd like to avoid re-generating `class_template_attr` every time a new `Foo` is instantiated, mainly because it's a resource intensive operation, but also because it should be the same for each `Foo` so it shouldn't be regenerated. I have looked high and low, but haven't been able to determine whether class attributes are recalculated when a new instance is created.

If they are recalculated, I would assume that I can define a setter that would check if `class_template_attr` exists, then either creates it or passes over the attribute if it already exists. I am currently using a metaclass to do this, but I wonder if this is the most Pythonic thing to do (or if I'm doing it right to begin with).

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.class_template_attr = some_resource_intensive_operation()

    @property
    def class_template_attr(cls):
        return cls.__class_template_attr

    @class_template_attr.setter
    def class_template_attr(cls, value):
        if cls.__class_template_attr is None:
            cls.__class_template_attr = value
        else:
            pass

def bar(input):
    value = some_operation
    return value


class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    def __init__(self, object_specific_input):
        self.instance_attr = bar(object_specific_input)

    @property
    def instance_attr(self):
        return self.__instance_attr

    @instance_attr.setter
    def instance_attr(self, value):
        self.__instance_attr = value
```

***Note***: I realise that the getter/setter for the instance attribute is overkill here, but I'm using them for a specific purpose that I won't go into for the sake of the MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I could have easily tested my own question as follows:

```
import random, string

def get_random_string():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))

random.seed(10)
class TestClassAttributeInstantiation:
    class_attr = get_random_string()
    def __init__(self):
        self.inst_attr = get_random_string()
```

Then, in an interpreter:

```
>>> TestClassAttributeInstantiation.class_attr
'OLPFVV'
>>> foo = TestClassAttributeInstantiation()
>>> foo.class_attr
'OLPFVV'
>>> foo.inst_attr
'QENIGY'
>>> bar = TestClassAttributeInstantiation()
>>> bar.class_attr
'OLPFVV'
>>> bar.inst_attr
'ZBWPJH'
```

As you can see, `class_attr` is set when the class is defined rather than when instantiated. This is evident in the fact that all instantiations have a `class_attr` with the same value AND in that the reference to the class also has that value.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why do you think that if you had not got the most basic of attributes in classes and instances, you'd succeed in writing metaclasses.

In fact, what you described as your need, is the basic behavior of objects in Python: your attribute is computed when the class body is executed (usually at module import time), once, and is available in all instances.

Moreover, if there was code in one instance doing something like: `self.class_template_attr = "new value"`, that would create a new attribute in that instance only, which would shadow the class attribute - but just for that instance. The original value would remain the default visible value for all other instances.

Now, about your metaclass: ou try to create a property on the metaclass itself and have it cascading down to the classes - that would certainly be overkill by a long shot.

There are some problems with your implementation as well - but starting with a non-error: while a "@property" would work on a metaclass and be available as a property on the class object, that would work, but you won't find an example for this in any docs: due to the fact they are not meant to be used in this way. They work because Python is extremely consistent in its rules, and then, classes, being objects and instances of the metaclass, are no exception to the descriptor protocol which is "what makes `property` work": a descriptor on the metaclass will be used for attribute retrieval on the class. However, the same descriptor on the metaclass **will not** be used to retrieve the attribute from the instance of that class.

There are a few other problems on the implementation, but the overwhelming redundancy is the the worst part. I'd add a side note not to rely on the double underscore prefix for "private" attributes too much. It can be useful on occasion, but it certainly is much less so than on languages with proper `public`, `private` and `protected` modifiers - they are more of use to prevent name clashes in a complicated class hierarchy using multiple inheritance and mixins, and will just get in your way sooner or later if used otherwise.

## Attribute retrieval in Python

On making `myinstance.myattr`:

1. Python will first check if the attribute exists in the clas of myinstance and, if so, if it is a descriptor (the class for the attribute value should have the `__get__` method. `property` implements that). If yes, that is called, and the resulting value is returned;
2. Python will check for the attribute on the instance itself. Ordinarily, as an entry on the instance's `__dict__`. If so, that value is returned.
3. Python looks for the attribute in the instance's class, regardless of it being a descriptor.
4. If not found, it will check if the class has a `__getattr__` method - that will be called with the intended attribute name, and either return a value or raise AttributeError.
5. If nothing is found this far, the search fails, and AttributeError is raised.

Note that for steps (1), (3) and (4) above, the class is searched, but not its own metaclass - instead, the search follows through the inheritance chain: in each of these steps the superclasses (in the order they show  in `myinstance.__class__.__mro__`) are searched for the attribute.

## using `property` for a read-only class attribute

If setting a plain class attribute is not enough, and you'd like to prevent instances from accidentally overwriting the instance value with  `self.myattr = "foo"`, a readonly property can be created on the class body. No need to resort to metaclasses.

Note that this still won't prevent the attribute from being overwritten in the class itself (with `self.__class__.myattr = "new value"` - if ou want to prevent *that*, then you'd need a metaclass and customize its  `__setattr__` method. That is the Pythonic concept of "consenting adults": if one writes all the way `self.__class__.myattr = "new value"` , they are *very* concerned to change the attribute, regardless of the intent of the class author, and willing to assume responsibility for that).

Anyway, for instance imutable attributes, and, as an extra, you get your expensive value lazily computed: it will be computed at the first occasion it will be actually needed, not at module import time: there is a trade off: you gain agility at app startup and pay the cost for that computation when it is actually first used:

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def my_attribute(self):
         if not hasattr(self, "_my_attribute"):
              self._my_attribute = some_resource_intensive_operation()
         return self._my_attribute
```

Now that - it is all that is needed. No "setter": when reading the value for the first time, the value is computed and stored in a "secret" private position. Withut the setter, one gets an attribute error on trying to set its value in an instance. No metaclasses needed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the class attribute is calculated when the class is defined/imported. Even if it wasn't, it would be more simple/pythonic to define that attribute as a property and check for its existence with ```hasattr``` before assigning.

Even though the metaclass example works, it's very non-pythonic and additionally is several orders of overkill.

Comment: Yes. (this text to reach minimum comment lenght)